# Defining GenericOf<T> to extract generic M used by another generic T

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am attempting to define a function that uses generics in the following way:

```
public fetch<M extends Model, T extends Service<M> = Service<M>>(service: string): T {
  return this.services[service]<M, T>();
}
```

where `Service` requires a generic `M extends Model`. Now, `T` is an extension of `Service` that has a generic that extends `Model`, for instance  `UserService<UserModel>`.

The above works but question is, is there a way to define the above function `fetch` so that I do not have to specify `M` explicitly, for instance:

```
// This is obviously bogus but I think it gets my point across.
public fetch<T extends Service<GenericOf<T>>>(service: string): T {
  return this.services[service]<GenericOf<T>, T>();
}
```

I have looked around and imagined it would be a Utility Type of sort that would allow me to get the generic used in a type. So would I be able to define an operator that extracts the generic of the type provided to it `type M = GenericOf<UserService>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a fully-general `GenericOf` type like how you want; consider this example:

```
type Foo<T> = {foo: T, bar: number}
type Bar<T> = {foo: string, bar: T}

type FooTest = GenericOf<Foo<string>>
type BarTest = GenericOf<Bar<number>>
```

Here, `FooTest` would have to be `string` and `BarTest` would have to be `number`; but both are defined as `GenericOf<...>` of the same type `{foo: string, bar: number}`. Clearly any `GenericOf` helper type cannot give two different results for the same input.

That said, you can define something like `GenericOf` if you only need to use it with a *specific* generic type:

```
type FooGenericOf<T extends Foo<any>> = T extends Foo<infer U> ? U : never
type BarGenericOf<T extends Bar<any>> = T extends Bar<infer U> ? U : never
```

Then `FooGenericOf<Foo<string>>` will be `string` and `BarGenericOf<Bar<number>>` will be `number`.

Comment: Thank you @kaya3, your post definitely shines some light on what I am going for. A direct application of the specific type gives me an ```excessively deep``` error but that is fine.

Comment: I will accept the post because it clearly illustrates why a general approach would not work and provided an alternative solution which I am definitely okay with applying.